# Pad leading zeros in regex substring with python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to increment a substring with regex. The strings look like this...

```
test = 'Project_S01_E02'
```

at the moment I have..

```
new = re.sub('E[0-9]{2}', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)[1:]) + 1), test)
```

where test becomes

```
Project_S01_3
```

I want to return

```
Project_S01_E03
```

How do I pad the leading zeros and 'E' into the test string?

Comment: Try using `'{:02}'.format(x.group(0)[1:])` instead of the double-cast.

Comment: Actually, in your case that would be: `lambda x: '{:02}'.format(int(x.group(0)[1:]) + 1)`

Comment: Thanks - this is almost the correct answer. I needed 'E' also - `lambda x: 'E{:02}'.format(int(x.group(0)[1:]) + 1)`